# Incorrect decoding in Mongo-go-driver

Tags: mongodb, go

For example, I have this structure:

```
type Overview struct {
    Symbol               string             `json:"Symbol,omitempty"`
    AssetType            string             `json:"AssetType,omitempty"`
    Name                 string             `json:"Name,omitempty"`
    Description          string             `json:"Description,omitempty"`
    ...
    ...
}
```

In addition to this, I have several other structures.
My function selects a suitable structure for Decode(), but when I try to get data from the database, I get the result in this form:

```
[
    {
        "Key": "_id",
        "Value": "618aa6f2a64cb8105a9c7984"
    },
    {
        "Key": "Symbol",
        "Value": "IBM"
    },
    {
        "Key": "FiscalYearEnd",
        "Value": "December"
    },
    ...
    ...
]
```

I expect a response in the form of my structure, but I get such an array. I tried declaring the structure for the response myself: `var result models.Overview`. After that, the problem disappeared, but this is not the solution for my problem

There is my function:

```
var (
    models map[string]interface{}
)

func init() {
    models = make(map[string]interface{})
    models["Overview"] = models.Overview{}
    models["Earnings"] = models.Earnings{}
    ...
    ...
}
func GetDbData(collection string, db *mongo.Database, filter bson.D) (interface{}, error) {
    var result = models[collection] // Choosing a structure
    res := db.Collection(collection).FindOne(context.TODO(), filter)
    err := res.Decode(&result)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return result, nil
}
```

I can't understand why this is happening, I hope that someone has already encountered this problem and will be able to help me

Comment: `result` is an `interface{}`, so you are only decoding into an `*interface{}`. Use a pointer to the correct type.

Comment: @JimB Thanks, but I don't understand how to do it yet

Comment: You ned a pointer to the value to decode into, e.g. `&models.Earnings{}`.

Comment: @JimB thank you, it helped me

Answer (score 0):

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/GODRIVER-988

```
Another approach to solve this can be by first decoding it into bson.M type and then unmarshalling it to your struct. Yes, this is not optimal.

eg:

func GetMonthStatusByID(ctx context.Context, id string) (interface{}, error) {
 var monthStatus interface{}
 filter := bson.M\{"_id": id}
 err := db.Collection("Months").FindOne(ctx, filter).Decode(&monthStatus)
 return monthStatus, err
}
The above snippet should be changed to:

func GetMonthStatusByID(ctx context.Context, id string) (interface{}, error) {
 var monthStatus interface{}
 filter := bson.M\{"_id": id}
tempResult := bson.M{}
 err := db.Collection("Months").FindOne(ctx, filter).Decode(&tempResult)
if err == nil {   
    obj, _ := json.Marshal(tempResult)
    err= json.Unmarshal(obj, &monthStatus)
}
 return monthStatus, err
}
```